# SQL Query get row rank or position on the main select query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc, window-functions

I'm trying to get the Rank of a specific row from my `SELECT` query.

Here's my table :

```
| PID   | Age   |
|------ |-----  |
| 5295  | 27    |
| 4217  | 26    |
| 2935  | 25    |
| 8706  | 24    |
```

My query and code: `I'm using SQL Server`

```
$x = 0;
$query = odbc_exec($connect, "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY Age DESC"); // Ordering by "Age" Descending
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)) {
    $x++;
    if($row['PID'] == 2935) { break; // Stop }
}

echo $x; // output "3"
```

This method works, but the question is can this be done with simple standalone `SQL Query` instead of `looping` through all results then incrementing `$x` variable to get the `specified row` rank. because this table contains thousands of entries which will be a little laggy while looping till it find the desired row then stop looping.

The logic of this ranking since I order with `Age` descending, so for example it will start with `27` with rank `1` along to `24` with rank `4`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you  using MySQL? Or SQL Server?

Comment: using SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` in a subquery to assign a rank to each record, then filter out in the outer query on the row you are interested in:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(order by age desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where pid = 2935
```

In MySQL, window functions are supported in version 8.0 only. In SQL Server, they have been available for a long time.